# unexpected_token on Ajax PUT/POST after upgrade jQuery, from 1.4.2 to 1.71

Tags: jquery, jersey, jax-rs

I developed an application using java jersey (jax-rs), a lot of jquery and JSON for transfer protocol.

After 2 years is come the time to upgrade to the new release of jquery, but doing this, I register an unexpected_token error on PUT and POST HTTP Methods.

I think that this issue happens on parsing result json message, because i can see POST and PUT effects on MySQL.

jQuery is the only thing I changed… What's changed on it?

Comment: I analized HTTP Headers on GET (working) and PUT (not working), looking for the differences: The first one has a specific **Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01**. The second one has instead a generic **Accept:*/***. I think they could be the reason. I'm investigating on it.

Comment: I Solved my issue!
I'm using a jquery rest plugin, bade by Nathan Bubna, that sets dataType: "rest" on ajax options, before to send the request: 

        `options: {
            dataType: "rest", // altered $.ajax default
            onlyNest: true, // altered $.values default
            // on-element options
            setValues: true,
            getValues: true
        },`

Editing dataType to "json" instead of "rest", everything works fine.

Thank's a lot, Davide.